# how to do column grouping in table or list

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a problem in SSRS reporting.

I have a data like this

```
BILLNO    |  AMT 
----------+--------
123       | 1000.00
1223      | 2000.00
```

I need to show in table or list in following way

```
123:1000.00    1223:2000.00
```

I tried by applying column and row grouping on two unique keys but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

So you need to show both the values in the same cell?

Firstly, assuming that you want to display this in a vertical list, you can simply add both values to a single text box.

1. Add BillNo to the cell
2. Add a colon in plain text
3. Create a new placeholder in the textbox (by right clicking), and set the Value of this to `=Fields!Amount.Value`

The design looks like this

[image]

And the output like this

[image]

Alternatively, if you want them side by side, create a matrix with column groupings on BillNo (you can always delete the column header, but not the associated groupings to improve your layout if you wish)

[image] ---> [image]